# Java desktop application with continuous communication between many clients and one server. How to properly set communication between devices?

Tags: java, security, io, nio, communication

I am creating a javafx application that can communicate with a server over the internet and I need some clarification on how things should work.

I am using an SSLSocket between the client and server (to ensure some level of security).

In both the client and the server, I'm running an infinite while loop so that they are both in constant communication with one another. ie:

```
 SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
            this.socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket(this.host, this.port);
            this.socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});
            this.socket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] {"TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"});
            this.writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream()));
            this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
...

public void run() {
        this.setSocket(); // creates the connection in another thread
        try{
            while(true){
                this.input = this.reader.readLine(); /* problem 2 */ 
                if(this.reader.ready()) { /* problem 1 */ 
                    this.input = this.reader.readLine();
                    System.out.println(this.input +"\n------------------------------------");
                }

                if(this.output != null) {
                    // If the writer has a message that is ready to send send it.
                    System.out.println("writing to server: " + this.output);
                    this.writer.println(this.output);
                    this.writer.flush();
                    this.setOutput(null); 
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("broke");
        }
    }
```

Now I noticed a couple problems with this implementation that I have a few proposed solutions to.

1. I noticed that the BufferedReader.ready() method doesn't return true until BufferedReader.readLine() is called and there is data to be read. So I moved the this.reader.readLine() method call to right before the this.reader.ready() line.
2. This resulted in the while loop to halt and wait for the this.reader.readLine() method to finish reading (which it never does since the server isn't sending any data to the client (at least not continuously - the server sends data to the client after it recieves a request from the client). By halting the while loop, the code doesn't ever update the output value, and therefore is unable to send a response to the server (effectively locking out the client from communicating with the server even though a secure connection has been made.
3. After some light reading on this issue, I determined that I could solve it by using an NIO (non-blocking input output) communication as my example is currently using blocking input output communication. But after looking through some examples, the setup looks rather complicated and I'm not sure if I want to spend the time to learn it unless absolutely necessary.
4. Which leads me to an alternate approach. If I pushed the bufferedReader and PrintWriter onto seperate threads, then the reader can be in a halting infinite while loop without blocking the writer thus effectively solving the problem while allowing continuous communication in a blocking io setting.

Now before I go implementing any of these solutions, I wanted to know if there are any reason(s) against either implementing NIO or just pushing blocking io operations onto seperate threads.

Is there another approach I did not consider? Which is more standard in a professional setting?

Comment: If you want to have a 'quick' result you can go with separate threads but I would use NIO since it's standardized and more efficient